# Django - order queryset alphabetically for cyrillic symbols

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have an issue with default ordering of cyrillic CharField's in Django. Is there a way to order cyrillic words alphabetically?

```
Taxonomy.objects.filter(type=tax_type).order_by('name')
```

This ordering returns me such data:

[image]

For english words ordering works as expected:

[image]

Shell output is exactly the same:

```
In [3]: Taxonomy.objects.filter(type="COUNTRY").order_by('name').values_list('id', 'name')
Out[3]: [(30, 'Abkhazija'), (31, 'Armenia'), (33, 'Gruzia'), (53, 'Kipr'), (59, 'Nepal'), (56, 'Thailand'), (46, 'Turkey'), (52, 'USA')]

In [4]: Taxonomy.objects.filter(type="PLACE").order_by('name').values_list('id', 'name')
Out[4]: [(42, 'Дон'), (49, 'Крым'), (73, 'Алтай'), (4, 'Архыз'), (71, 'Плато Путорана'), (44, 'Адыгея'), (75, 'Байкал'), (64, 'Домбай'), (11, 'Кавказ'), (69, 'Хибины'), (35, 'Карелия'), (54, 'Эверест'), (32, 'Эльбрус'), (34, 'Камчатка'), (51, 'Псковская область'), (19, 'Заграничный'), (50, 'Подмосковье'), (65, 'Приэльбрусье'), (60, 'Ленинградская область')]
```

Comment: I guess your problem is related to some translation app. Do you use any?

Comment: Nope.. I don't. Fields are stored directly in to database (it's not a translation)

Comment: Ok, can you provide some more details? What output of query above if you run it directly in the shell with `./manage.py shell` cmd? Where you specify this queryset, somewhere in django admin class? Or elsewhere?

Comment: Also, I didn't realize how you store model field translation.

Comment: 1) There is no translation in the project (I've translated the names manually)
2) Added shell output to the question

Comment: Sounds odd to me. You sorted counties by name stored in db and than translate it with django.utils.translation or something else? In that case you should sort carefully on client with js or use translation app like modeltranslation

Comment: Noooo!!! It just an example where I show that english words orders in corect way and russian are not

Comment: There is NO translation at all

Comment: Oh, you really know how to confuse. Check raw query returns the same result as Django queryset. I'm sure the problem is related to your db settings (probably lc_collate) but not Django.